# Having issues with retrieving state asynchronously in React child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, react-props

I'm having a really funny issue retrieving and displaying info from my React app's state in *only one* nested child.

What I'm trying to do is similar to to this [react-router tutorial for recursive paths](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths). I have an Admin route, which takes the user to nested sections that the user can edit. I'm successfully passing props down to each component, rendering information held within the app's state, until I reach a certain point.

my URL is: **/admin/label/posts/edit/:post**

my component looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const EditingPost = props => {
  const index = props.match.params.post
  const post = props.posts[index]
  return(
    <div>
      {post.title}
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(EditingPost)
```

My error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
EditingPost
src/pages/Admin/Label/EditingPost.js:9
   6 |   const post = props.posts[index]
   7 |   return(
   8 |     <div>
>  9 |       {post.title}
  10 |     </div>
  11 |   )
  12 | }
```

However, when I **console.log(post)** the app throws 5 logs, the first 2 are *undefined*, the next 3 contain the proper information that I'm looking for. What I thought was that I'd need to wait until the information is available before rendering the component's html. Yet, when I threw logs into other components, I noticed the same behavior; multiple logs, the first one or two are *undefined*, the rest contain the information desired, then all the components load properly.

What I can't understand is why I'm having trouble with this particular component. I know the information I need is coming through, but for some reason I'm unable to use it like I would normally.

I've googl'd my fingers off, tried importing helpful libraries, tried using promises, tried implementing everything I could before asking here.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated! I hope all this makes sense to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the following change to your function:

```
const EditingPost = props => {
  const index = props.match.params.post
  const post = props.posts[index];
  const title = post ? post.title : '';
  return(
    <div>
      {title}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: anomaaly this is the exact, simple solution I'm looking for. Thanks so much!